# Better way to pass bool variable as parameter?

Tags: c++, readability

I am wondering if there is a better way to write this for better readability.
If you have a function like below,

```
void animal(bool hasFourLegs, bool hasHead, bool hasBody);
```

When you call the function, you will end up with something like

```
animal(true, false, true);
```

and this makes me go take a look at the definition every time I encounter function like this.

SO...

I do something like this!

```
const bool HAS_FOURLEGS = true;
const bool NO_HEAD = false;
const bool HAS_BODY = true;

animal(HAS_FOURLEGS, NO_HEAD, HAS_BODY);
```

But I do not like to declare `const bool` every time I call the function.

It seems like CPP does not support something like

```
animal(bool hasFourlegs = true, bool hasHead = false, bool hasBody = true);
```

Is there any better and shorter way?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, do not declare variables in all capital letter style. It's usually intended for macros

Comment: this is why it is important to have a good IDE. with just a hover you can see the function signature

Comment: the signature of your function is exactly what your IDE is supposed to be telling you - don't use plain text editors

Comment: I use vim with YouCompleteMe. When I do coding, it works pretty good. But when I am reading, oh man.. lol

Comment: You could consider declaring an `enum` and using it as a bitmask : `enum animaltype { HAS_FOURLEGS = 1, HAS_HEAD = 2, HAS_BODY = 4}`, and then just call `animal(HAS_FOURLEGS | HAS_BODY)`. This feels much more C than C++, though.

Comment: Why is there no animal class ? Of course the problem would then maybe move to the constructor of that class. But the enum solution is a perfect fit for that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When I run into issues related to this I sometimes create an `enum` even when there are only 2 expected choices:

For example, instead of the following function declaration:

```
bool search(..., bool recursive);
```

I'd go with:

```
enum class SearchOpt
{
    Recursive,
    NonRecursive
};

bool search(..., SearchOpt opt);
```

Therefore, the calling syntax changes from:

```
bool found = search(..., true);
```

to:

```
bool found = search(..., SearchOpt::Recursive);
```

Note: this avoids you having to create your own constants every time you call the function.

### Edit

As others have suggested, instead of having separate `bool`s for each option and thereby a separate `enum` for each it would make sense to have a single `enum` configured as bit flags.

Comment: Something that's implied here is that you then need to code `if (opt == SearchOpt.Recursive)` rather than `if (recursive)` inside the `search` function. The alternative, as you've used an enum class, is to use `if (static_cast<bool>(opt))`, which is untidy. It would be nice to be able to declare and implement something like `bool operator bool(SearchOpt value) { return value == SearchOpt::Recursive) }` which would be better in the `search` function, but slightly nasty otherwise (IMO  :-) ), however `operator bool` can't be overridden in this way :-( )

Answer (score 10):

Use flags:

```
  enum {
    HAS_LEGS = 0x01,
    HAS_HEAD = 0x02,
    HAS_BODY = 0x04,
  };

  void animal(int properties);

  animal(HAS_LEGS | HAS_HEAD);
```

Comment: Then use type-safe, introspection-aware flags like `QFlags` from the Qt library. Or overload some operator such as `operator<<` to create a class factory.

Comment: @SergeyA: In the sense that they are soo fast, short time to code, less lines of code while keeping code readable, keep interfaces stable over time? ;-p

Comment: @cfi, not really. In the sense that they are polluting namespaces (HAS_LEGS  only has meaning for animal(), but will be visible for everybody else (and yes, I know about class enums), they are painful to maintain, they are cryptic when looking at call stack... Enough?

Answer (score 3):

One other option is to use a class  to hold the parameters where they're closely related:

```
struct AnimalOptions {
  bool hasHead, hasBody, hasLegs;
  AnimalOptions() : hasHead(false), hasBody(false), hasLegs(false);
}

...

AnimalOptions opt;
  opt.hasHead = true;

  animal(opt);
```

This technique is useful whenever you have a function which seems to take a bunch of parameters with identical types, whose order isn't easily remembered. It's just as useful when your function take several `int`s.

Comment: With a bit more boilerplate, one can chain the modifications: `AnimalOptions().hasHead(false).hasBody(true)`

Answer (score 2):

As a alternative to the other answers, I liked [tagged_bool](https://github.com/akrzemi1/explicit/blob/master/include/ak_toolkit/tagged_bool.hpp) that [Andrzej Krzemieński](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2017/02/16/toggles-in-functions/) came up with on his blog.

Answer (score 1):

Strange no one suggested named parameters from Boost.parameter: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/parameter/doc/html/index.html

Comment: To be truly honest, I've never seen Boost.parameter in real world code :-}

Comment: This feels like using an atomic bomb to crack a nut. (And likewise, never seen anyone actually use it)

Answer (score 0):

Comments are your friends!

```
animal(   true,   //hasFourLegs
          false,  //hasHead
          true    //hasBody
      );
```

Comment: comments like this cannot make up for bad code. Don't write comment write readable code.

Comment: This would make it to leaderboard of my 'Worst Comment Ever' competition. While the first place is fixed for "++i; // Increment i" comments and the second is permanently occupied by class A { A(); // Constructor this is also notable example.

Comment: This is in the same category as /*ref*/ for parameters passed as mutable &. It's the reason that C# introduced keyword "ref" so that callers would have to be annotated. The problem on the boolean parameters is the same issue -- we want the language to force the call site to be annotated. To me, this seems like an IDE issue, not a language issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could use bitwise values, as follows:

```
const int hasLegs = 0x01;
const int noHead = 0x02;
const int hasBody = 0x04;
```

Then call `animal` with any combination of the above, e.g.:
animal(hasLegs + hasBody);

Decalre `animal` with a single `int` parameter.

```
inside `animal`, test the bits:
if (parameter & haasBody)
{
    // it has a body....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C++20 has [designated initializers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Designated_initializers) as part of aggregate initialization. You could make a struct with the boolean parameters and pass the struct by value. You can even have default parameter values.

```cpp
struct AnimalParts {
    bool hasFourLegs = false;
    bool hasHead = true;
    bool hasBody = true;
}

void animal(AnimalParts parts);
```

Then use it like this:

```cpp
animal({.hasFourLegs = true, .hasHead = false});
```

This comes very close to the named parameters idiom you suggested. In terms of compilation both options seem to produce comparable output, see on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/96Wjrd).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's a correct way to go, but still I cannot resist sharing this thought.

Let's imagine the function is not yours, but rather from some popular API which is hard to change.

```
void animal(bool hasFourLegs, bool hasHead, bool hasBody);
```

In this case it's possible to call it like this:

```
animal(bool("hasFourlegs"), !bool("hasHead"), bool("hasBody"));
```

The C-string is always a non zero pointer, which is converted to `true`.

One possible downside is compilation time...?
Another is increase in length of code rows...